# Excel syntax with nested search function

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to create a function that will look for a letter in column A and put the corresponding name to column E.

It is easy if the column A only contained the one letter only ("S" or "C" for example). Then the function would go:

```
=IF(A234="S";"Salt";IF(A234="C";"Coriander";""))
```

However, in column A there is S1, S10, or C15, C105 etc.

Then, apparently, I need the function **SEARCH** to only search for the key letter

**However, this nested IF doesn't work for the second IF :**

```
        =IF(SEARCH("C";$A234);"Coriander";IF(SEARCH("S";$A234);"Salt";""))
```

What's more, I want to add an **IFERROR** to give me blank cell if none of the **IF** conditions are met, probably something like this

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("C";$A234);"Coriander";IF(SEARCH("S";$A234);"Salt";""));"")
```

Can somebody help solve the syntax error? Thanks in advance

[image: How it should look like - each]

Comment: ................see my update.

Comment: It appears from your screenshot you are concerned only with the first letter. If so you can use LEFT to extract the first letter to compare like IF(LEFT(A234;1)="S"

Comment: You are righ eshwar, thanks, I just modifired my original idea with nested if with your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *MATCH()* with wildcards.  This formula:

```
=MATCH("*S*",A1:A1,0)
```

will give a 1 if there is an "S" in **A1**, otherwise an error.  We can use this to nest the tests:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*S*",A1:A1,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*C*",A1:A1,0)),"","Coriander"),"Salt")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work... it just changes all the rows with Salt as soon as something with C (i.e C10) appears anywhere in the A column... I need the formula to work out a result for each row individually

Comment: @teaspoon  my computer uses *commas* in the formulas, your computer may require the *semi-colon* ........have you done the translation ??

Comment: @teaspoon I did not understand the question and will remove the answer.

Comment: Yes, I also had to translate the functions into my localized installation of Exel :-)

Comment: @teaspoon  Is this cell-by-cell test any better ?